# ifort: command line warning about -fallow-argument-mismatch

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option
'-fallow-argument-mismatch'

I get the above error while using make command in CosmoMC/source
directory.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What help do you need? The warning is quite clear: `-fallow-argument-mismatch` isn't an option supported by ifort. Do you want to know what the gfortran option of that name means, what the equivalent for ifort is, or how to change your Makefile to use the correct option, or something else?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. To get a really useful answer you have to tell us more. What exactly are you doing? Which Makefile are you using? How are you configuring it?

Comment: Yes. I think that would be better to know how to change the Makefile in order to resolve the error without calling gfortran. Just to be sure that Makefile is getting complied with ifort.

Comment: Obviously just remove that option from the list of options where it appears.  But you don't have to; it's a warning, not an error (because ifort expects stuff like this to happen when you use it with a command line designed for another compiler).  And if you want your Makefile to work with other compilers you may need to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

What you got is just a warning, not an error. You can safely ignore it, unless the missing option causes some other error down the line.

The issue is exactly what the warning message says, `fallow-argument-mismatch` is a gfortran option, not an Intel Fortran option.